# VS Code - How To Automatically Convert Inline Style Strings To React Inline Style Objects

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Basically, I want to paste any web page's HTML into VS Code, push a button, and viola it converts stuff like this...

```
<div id="txt_2" style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:0px;width:958px;height:56px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

into this...

```
<div 
    id="txt_2" 
    style={{
        position: "absolute", 
        left: "1px", 
        top: "0px", 
        width: "958px", 
        height: "56px", 
        overflow: "hidden"
    }}></div>
```

...with just a push of a button, just like this website can do:
https://casbin.org/CssToAndFromReact/

While that website is great, I still must copy/paste, copy/paste back and forth.  If a page has hundreds of style strings, you can see how that can eat up time.

I looked but saw no posts specifically addressing this on Stack.

Comment: you can use a snippet to transformation the selected text

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you.  I was aware of that.  However, this is more like copy the body tag of any website, drop it into VS Code (so it's huge amount of HTML) and you run 1 command to format all - includes changing "class=" to "className=", etc.  Full on react component's return from any webpage's body tag, intelligently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Casbin team. The source code of https://casbin.org/CssToAndFromReact/ is the master branch of repo: https://github.com/casbin/CssToAndFromReact and it's deployed to the gh-pages branch.

We forked from https://github.com/htbkoo/CssToAndFromReact and add some changes. You can assemble a script to run automatically against multiple files via using our source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
This simple little tool (forked to htbkoo/CssToAndFromReact from staxmanade/CssToReact) is intended to help translate plain CSS into and back from the React in-line style specific JSON representation. Making it easy to copy and paste into an inline React component or a CSS stylesheet.
```

Visit https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter